# Отправка уведомлений из формы в Laravel&

Tags: laravel

У меня есть форма заполнения задачb, там есть автор и есть человек которому поручена задача. Мне нужно после добавления задачи, оправлять уведомление человеку которому поручена задача на почту. Подскажите может кто знает, как это можно реализовать?
Контролер добавления задачи:

```
class StoreController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(StoreRequest $request, Task $task)
    {

        $data = $request->validated();

      
         $data['file_task'] = Storage::disk('public')->put('/images', $data['file_task']);


        Task::firstOrCreate($data);

       
        return redirect()->route('serviceman.solution.index');
    }

}
```

Форма добавления задачи

```
 <section class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
                <div class="col-12">
                    <form action="{{route('serviceman.task.store')}}"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-group class = 25">
                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control w-25" name="author"
                                   value="{{Auth::user()->name }}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control w-25" name="name" placeholder="Тема"
                            value="{{old('name')}}">
                            @error('name')
                            <div class="text-danger">Это поле необходимо заполнить</div>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group class = w-25">
                            <label>Выберите рабочий центр</label>
                            <select name="rc_id" class="form-control">
                                @foreach($rcs as $rc)
                                    <option value="{{$rc->id}}"
                                        {{$rc->id == old('rc_id') ? ' selected' : ''}}
                                    >{{$rc->name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group class = w-25">
                            <label>Статус задачи</label>
                            <select name="status_id" class="form-control">
                                @foreach($statuses as $status)
                                    <option value="{{$status->id}}"
                                        {{$status->id == old('status_id') ? ' selected' : ''}}
                                    >{{$status->status}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group class = w-25">
                            <label>Тип проблемы</label>
                            <select name="problem_id" class="form-control">
                                @foreach($problems as $problem)
                                    <option value="{{$problem->id}}"
                                        {{$problem->id == old('problem_id') ? ' selected' : ''}}
                                    >{{$problem->name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group class = w-25">
                            <label>Ответственный</label>
                            <select name="user_id" class="form-control">
                                @foreach($users as $user)
                                    <option value="{{$user->id}}"
                                        {{$user->id == old('user_id') ? ' selected' : ''}}
                                    >{{$user->name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group class = w-25">
                            <label>Срок выполнения</label>
                            <input name="term" id="date" class="form-control" style="width: 100%; display: inline;" onchange="invoicedue(event);"
                                required="" type="date"  value="{{old('term')}}">
                        </div>
                        @error('term')
                        <div class="text-danger">Это поле необходимо заполнить</div>
                        @enderror
                        <div class="form-group class = w-50">
                            <label for="exampleInputFile">Добавить файл</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="custom-file">
                                    <input type="file" name="file_task"  class="custom-file-input" multiple>
                                    <label class="custom-file-label">Выберите файл</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <span class="input-group-text">Загрузка</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            @error('file_task')
                            <div class="text-danger">Это поле необходимо заполнить</div>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="summernote" >
                           <textarea id="summernote" name="description_task">
                               {{old('description_task')}}
                           </textarea>
                            @error('description_task')
                            <div class="text-danger">Это поле необходимо заполнить</div>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                            <div class="for-group">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn  btn-secondary" value="Добавить"></input>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!-- ./col -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: Вот так: [Notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/notifications)

Answer (score 0):

Вам не нужно делать это в форме. И не нужно в контроллере. Предлагаю сделать это в [Observer'е](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#observers) после того, как задача будет создана.

***Пример:***

```php
class TaskObserver
{
    public function created(Task $task)
    {
        Mail::to($task->user)->send(new TaskCreated($task));
    }
}
```